# how to format date in "YYYY-mm-dd" format using hql?

Tags: database, hibernate, sql-server-2008, date, hql

When I use MS SQL database, I do this to convert date in timestamp to "YYYY-mm-dd" format.

```
CONVERT(DATE, "Timestamp")
```

I need to do the same function using HQL.

Which function will remove all the time indices and give the date in "YYYY-mm-dd" format?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following that converts a date to a string with the specified format:

```
to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: Is there a chance this got removed or something?

Comment: @displayname It seems to depend on the database - see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to either use vendor-specific functions or extend the dialect. Unfortunately this isn't supported out of the box in Hibernate (not sure why as would have thought it was simple to implement).

Extending the dialect is simple and is a better option as it keeps your application database-agnostic and works seamlessly across the app.

### Option 1: Extend the dialect(s)

Create classes for the dialects that you want to extend such as:

```
class ExtendedOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    ExtendedOracle10gDialect() {
        // Add a generic 'date_format' function that can be used across databases
        registerFunction("date_format", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "to_char(?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

Then change your datasource to use the custom dialect, for example by changing hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">com.mycompany.dialect.ExtendedOracle10gDialect</property>
```

You can then use `DATE_FORMAT(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')` in your HQL

### Option 2: Use vendor-specific functions

MySQL / MariaDB:

```
DATE_FORMAT(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

SQL Server:

```
FORMAT(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Oracle / PostgreSQL:

```
TO_CHAR(MYDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

instead of `CONVERT()`.

Comment: What if you want the month in a different language?

Answer (score 2):

Use this hive function:

```
date_format(mydatewithtimestamp,'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `TO_DATE` function.

Comment: no proper methods we sould handle it using java code